# Solution of the differential equation $y=x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{b}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation:

$$y=x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{b}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$$ where $b$ is a real constant.

I tried solving it by taking $\frac{dy}{dx}=t$, then solving quadratic equation for roots. But this method gives complicated differential equation once I write expression for roots. Could someone suggest a better approach.

Comment: One obvious solution is $y=x+b$, or more generally, $y=cx+\frac bc$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How can you directly say it?

Comment: Just plug it in

Answer (score 7):

This is a [Clairaut equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut's_equation).

Therefore, you can differentiate both sides w.r.t $x$ to obtain:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{b\cdot \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$$
Factoring gives:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}\left(x-\frac{b}{(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}\right)=0$$
Now, solve for the following separately:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=0$$
And:
$$x-\frac{b}{(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if this helps.

let $m = \frac{dy}{dx}.$ now we can write your differential equation  $y=x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{b}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$ as $$y = xm + \frac b m  $$
solving this quadratic equation, you have $$2x\ m = y \pm \sqrt{y^2 - 4bx}\to 2x\frac{dy}{dx} = y\pm\sqrt{y^2 - 4bx}  $$